# Hide "Delete Note" link in Order Notes Panel

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How do you hide the "Delete Note" link in the Order Notes panel? Is there a hook that can be used?

[image: Sample order note]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding this in your functions.php file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_delete_note_from_edit_order');
function hide_delete_note_from_edit_order()
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->post_type === "shop_order" && $screen->base === "post") {
        echo '<style>a.delete_note { display:none; }</style>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I just removed `$screen` and the condition below it to make it simple. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by [Dharmishtha Patel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/135085/dharmishtha-patel) is a good method to use. 
Another method requiring less processing is the "Additional CSS" functionality.

Within your Dashboard select "*Appearance | Customize | Additional CSS*" to display an edit box.

If the style you want to change is a.delete_note type the following;

```
.a.delete_note { display: none; }
```

or perhaps

```
a.delete_note { display: none }
```

This method can be used for hiding many elements and overrides existing css styles.

[More information can be found here.](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/)

Comment: I think the custom css doesn't affect the admin panel.

Comment: @wptent Sorry, I was unaware this was within the admin panel. :( Having said that, the css options are good for hiding other things on your blog and perhaps you can use it for something else. :) Good luck.

Comment: All good. thank you nonetheless.